# Search Box Query Settings

Tags: search, custom-list

I am trying to setup my search box to query only from the three list webparts I have on the same page.

I have gone into the manage result sources but have been unable to make this happen.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the environment (version, cloud/on-prem) and context of the situation (a screenshot would be nice).

Comment: I am using SharePoint Online 2013. I have three lists that I want to receive results from. I only want results from the 3 lists. I specifically want to search a custom ID column that I have created in each of the lists.